# JavaFX updating current location by setOnKeyPressed

Tags: java, javafx

im currently learning JavaFX and i decided to make a simple adventure game. A description of the location with available exits is displayed in the text area and in the text field the user types in which direction he wants to go. However, I encountered a problem: after choosing the direction I have to press enter again to properly update current location and available exits. I was able to discover, that in current version this is due to the way i update the "loc" variable which is responsible for current location description. I have no idea how can i fix it, or how should i change the way it works. Can someone help me with that? Thank you in advance for your help

Location class:

```
package sample.LocationsSystem;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Location {
private final int locationID;
private final String description;
private final Map<String, Integer> exits;

public Location(int locationID, String description) {
    this.locationID = locationID;
    this.description = description;
    this.exits = new HashMap<>();
}

public void addExit(String direction, int location) {
    exits.put(direction, location);
}

public int getLocationID() {
    return locationID;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public Map<String, Integer> getExits() {
    return new HashMap<String, Integer>(exits);
}
}
```

Locations with descriptions and exits:

```
package sample.LocationsSystem;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Locations {

private static Map<Integer, Location> locationsMap = new HashMap<>();

public Locations() {
    initializeMap();
}

public static Map<Integer, Location> getLocationsMap() {
    return locationsMap;
}

public static void initializeMap(){
    locationsMap.put(0, new Location(0,"You entered the dungeon"));
    locationsMap.put(1, new Location(1,"You are in a narrow corridor"));
    locationsMap.put(2, new Location(2,"You are in round basement. You can see many doors around you"));
    locationsMap.put(3, new Location(3,"You are in a dark corridor. Strange noises are coming from the door just before you"));
    locationsMap.put(4, new Location(4,"Location 4"));
    locationsMap.put(5, new Location(5,"It's nothing here. Turn back"));
    locationsMap.put(6, new Location(6,"It's a broom cupboard."));
    locationsMap.put(7, new Location(7,"It's just a corridor"));
    locationsMap.put(8, new Location(8,"You entered into old throne room"));
    locationsMap.put(9, new Location(9,"It looks like an old armory"));
    locationsMap.put(10, new Location(10,"You can see a large pile of gold coins. That's what you came here for."));


    locationsMap.get(0).addExit("W",1);

    locationsMap.get(1).addExit("N",2);
    locationsMap.get(1).addExit("E",0);

    locationsMap.get(2).addExit("N",6);
    locationsMap.get(2).addExit("S",1);
    locationsMap.get(2).addExit("E",3);
    locationsMap.get(2).addExit("W",5);

    locationsMap.get(5).addExit("E",2);

    locationsMap.get(6).addExit("S",2);

    locationsMap.get(3).addExit("E",4);
    locationsMap.get(3).addExit("W",2);

    locationsMap.get(4).addExit("N",7);
    locationsMap.get(4).addExit("W",3);

    locationsMap.get(7).addExit("S",4);
    locationsMap.get(7).addExit("E",8);

    locationsMap.get(8).addExit("N",10);
    locationsMap.get(8).addExit("S",9);
    locationsMap.get(8).addExit("W",7);

    locationsMap.get(9).addExit("N",8);


    Map<String, String> vocabulary = new HashMap<String, String>();
    vocabulary.put("NORTH", "N");
    vocabulary.put("SOUTH", "S");
    vocabulary.put("WEST", "W");
    vocabulary.put("EAST", "E");
}
}
```

And my Controller class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import sample.Characters.Player;
import sample.FightSystem.Fight;
import sample.LocationsSystem.Locations;

import java.util.Map;


public class Controller {

@FXML
TextField HPTextField;

@FXML
TextField enemyHP;

@FXML
TextField potionsTextField;

@FXML
TextField textField;

@FXML
TextArea mainTextArea;

public void clearTextField() {
    textField.clear();
}

int loc = 0;
public void initialize() {

    Player player = new Player("Player", 100, 10);
    Fight fight = new Fight();

    HPTextField.setText(Integer.toString(player.getHp()));
    potionsTextField.setText(Integer.toString(player.getPotions().size()));

    mainTextArea.setText("Welcome to adventure game! \n=======PRESS ENTER TO START======");

    Locations locations = new Locations();
    Map<String, Integer> exits = locations.getLocationsMap().get(loc).getExits();

    textField.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {
        if (keyEvent.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {

            String direction = textField.getText().toUpperCase();

            mainTextArea.appendText(locations.getLocationsMap().get(loc).getDescription()
                    + "\n In which direction would you like to go? \nAvailable directions: ");

            for (String exit : exits.keySet()) {
                mainTextArea.appendText(exit + " ");
            }

            if (exits.containsKey(direction)) {
                loc = exits.get(direction);
            }
            textField.clear();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would create a text file with all the locations and another that tells the places you could go from each location. I would add a List of potential places to go to my Location Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example intended to give you an idea of how you may proceed with this and solve the location setting issue you currently have.

What the sample does is move to the starting location, then, every time the user moves to a new location, update the location, with appropriate feedback to the user in the provided text area.

The key difference to what is in your question, is that the following code will immediately update the current location reference and provide feedback on a move to a new location as soon as that move is made rather than the next time a key is pressed.

```
private static final int STARTING_LOC = 0;
private Locations locations = new Locations();
private int loc;

private TextArea mainTextArea = new TextArea();
private TextField textField = new TextField();

public void initialize() {
    mainTextArea.setText("Welcome to adventure game!");
    moveTo(STARTING_LOC);

    textField.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {
        if (keyEvent.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
            String direction = textField.getText().toUpperCase();
            Integer newLoc = getCurrentExits().get(direction);
            if (newLoc != null) {
                moveTo(newLoc);
            }

            textField.setText("");
        }
    });
}

private void moveTo(int newLoc) {
    this.loc = newLoc;
    mainTextArea.appendText(
        locations.getLocationsMap().get(loc).getDescription()
            + "\n In which direction would you like to go? \nAvailable directions: "
    );
    for (String exit : getCurrentExits().keySet()) {
        mainTextArea.appendText(exit + " ");
    }
}

private Map<String, Integer> getCurrentExits() {
    return locations.getLocationsMap().get(loc).getExits();
}
```

The example is loosely based on the code from your question, so some of the code required to compile it is contained in your question, not this answer.  The example is not intended to demonstrate a best practice for creating an adventure game.  It is just a short snippet rather than a complete program, and doesn't tie in to FXML.  It also assumes that static methods of your Locations class are replaced with non-static methods.

*Unrelated advice*

A couple of things you might think of doing differently:

1. Use [enumerated types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) as appropriate, for example a `Direction` enumerated type rather than a HashMap.
2. Store your location data in a JSON file, read using [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson).  A relational database could also be considered, but JSON will probably prove easier to work with, unless you end up with a lot more complicated requirements.
3. Name the locations with human readable names and refer to the exits using those same names, rather than integers.
4. Use references to location objects rather than an indexed int ID value.  For instance, getCurrentExits could return `Map<Direction, Location>` rather than `Map<String, Integer>`, so you have more representative typed information in your data structures.
5. Abstract out the core game engine from the UI so that it can be developed and tested independently of the UI, then inject game engine model instances and service instance calls into the UI interface as needed.

What you have currently is fine for a start, you don't need to implement any of the suggested ideas (and they could potentially make your application more complicated rather than less complicated, which you probably avoid at this stage), they are just some things that occurred to me as I was looking at your code, if you wanted to develop the application into something significantly larger or more complex.